# multidimensional key is overwriting the existing code in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hi guys i am new to PHP , i am trying to push new key and value in existing array, but it is not working as expected

> my code

```
<?php

  echo buildQueryForAccuracy(123,100,["5000"]);
  function buildQueryForAccuracy($gId, $worksheetId, $userIDs=null)
    {
        $query = [
            "size" => 0,
            "query" => [
                "bool" => [
                    "must" => [
                        ["term" => ["groupId" => $gId]],
                        ["term" => ["contentPath.contentId" => $worksheetId]],
                        ["terms" => ["userId" => $userIDs]],// not empty this condition has to come otherwise should not 
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            
        ];
        echo json_encode($query);
    }


?>
```

if `$userIDs` not empty then only i have to add that condition.so i have tried below like this

```
 if($userIDs){
        $query["query"]["bool"]["must"] =  ["terms" => ["userId" => $userIDs] ];
    }
```

Comment: Try `$query["query"]["bool"]["must"][] =  ["terms" => ["userId" => $userIDs] ];`

Answer (score 0):

As @Nick suggested you have to append to the array after checking the condition, currently you are replacing it.  [more on php array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```php
function buildQueryForAccuracy($gId, $worksheetId, $userIDs=null) {
        $query = [
            "size" => 0,
            "query" => [
                "bool" => [
                    "must" => [
                        ["term" => ["groupId" => $gId]],
                        ["term" => ["contentPath.contentId" => $worksheetId]],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            
        ];
        if($userIDs){
                $query["query"]["bool"]["must"][] =  ["terms" => ["userId" => $userIDs] ];
        }

        echo json_encode($query);
    }
```